# Ionic - Change font size of select options on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework

Im nearly certain this isn't possible within an iPhone app but the client has requested that the select input (slider interface at the bottom) has a smaller font size.

Is this possible within Ionic?

Comment: Can you provide a photo of what exactly you want changed?

Comment: It sound like just scss stuff

Comment: @maninakm Its the native select options on IOS